In React Native KeyboardAvoidingView is adding extra space until the first key is pressed, then rendering correctly after a key is pressed
I have a Bare React Native app that uses React Navigation, the entire app is wrapped in a KeyboardAvoidingView like this:
<SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        behavior={isIos ? "padding" : "height"}
    >
            <GestureHandlerRootView>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <AppStack />
                </NavigationContainer>
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</SafeAreaProvider>

Then within a stack screen I have a component with a FlatList and a text input:
<View
    style={{flex: 1}}
>
    <FlatList />
    <TextInput />
</View>

Everything displays correctly and works as desired except that on Android (both real device and emulator) the keyboard avoiding view adds extra space until the first key is pressed.
The screen before focusing the text input:

The screen after focusing the text input:

The screen after the first press on a keyboard character:

And then the extra space shows for a moment after the keyboard closes, before rendering correctly.

I have tried:

just wrapping that screen in KeyboardAvoidingView,
"padding", "height", and "position" for the behaviour prop,
having the KeyboardAvoidingView wrapped around each different level of navigator within the app.

How do I get it to render without the additional space immediately rather than after the first key is pressed?
